# error installing RPi.GPIO on Python

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am trying this out for the first time with not much success
I recently bought latest Raspberry PI 3 B+

I am trying to install RPi.GPIO via python 3.7 on my windows 10 machine.

I have successfully downloaded RPi.GPIO-0.6.3

when I run the install in the command window with '**pip install RPi.GPIO**'
its starts, and looks like it has been successful, but the process has errors!
the first one being **'Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO'**
It then indicates an error running **'setup.py install for RPi.GPIO'**

Lastly it then says that **[image: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required]**.

Any ideas of what has gone wrong and how can i fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your end goal?

Comment: I am wanting to learn Python, and be able to control the GPIO pins on the Raspberry PI, just to do basic things at first like turning LED's on and off, but I havent got the environment setup correctly as I get numerous errors, (when I try to import the module in IDLE I get:-   'import PRi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PRi' i thought RPi.GPIO' was for python but I am mistaken- and I somehow need to run that on the Raspberry PI instead..? im still trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: Was that a typo?  You need to be on the Pi and the command is `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`.  Note that letter case is important and needs to be correct.

Comment: yes sorry was Typo, I did mean 'import RPi.GPIO...thanks again for all your usefull feedback!

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by installing an RPi library on Windows 10?

Comment: I am totally new to this...I now know that it is meant to be installed on the PI - not on the PC running python! when I got my PI there were no instructions at all, have also learnt that i need to put an operating system on the micro SD card, so will go away and do this first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RPi.GPIO Python module only works on a Raspberry Pi.  It accesses the Raspberry Pi's GPIO and expects to be running under a Linux environment.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, i can confrim that I do have a Raspberyy PI. so am I actually doing something wrong, is the problem that I am running this in the cmd window of my windows machine? should I be running this somewhere else, i.e. some environment on my Raspberry PI? if so where is it & what is it called? sorry I am completely new to this

Comment: Yes.  To work the RPi.GPIO module requires 1) to be running on a Raspberry Pi, 2) to be running under the Linux operating system.

Comment: You could use putty (I think that is the name) to access a command window running on the Pi from your Windows PC.  That may be what you want to do.

Comment: Also see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/